# How to export an animated texture from Blender to WebGL?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, three.js, blend4web, webgl

I have an animated fire "burning" on a round plane by using the fire and smoke features on Blender. It's very similar to the one found in this [tutorial link.](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/make-fire-cycles/) I want to the render the model on three.js.
I tried the Blend4Web HTML format and only the texture of the fire doesn't appear.
I also, exported it to .json and collada with the three.js exporter. No results.

Do I use UV mapping? But the flame isn't a defined model.

Comment: Hi, please repeat your question on the Blend4Web forums, we'll try to help.

Comment: I never received the email to completely register with the forum.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an animated fire "burning" on a round plane by using the fire and smoke features on Blender. It's very similar to the one found in this link.

First of all Blend4Web engine doesn't export all from Blender - it works mostly with Blender Internal Render, so only Blender Internal Render nodes, particles and Physics can be exported to the engine. Cycles will not work and you can't export smoke simulation directly from blender to the engine.

> I want to render the model on three.js.

Blend4web and three.js cant be connected between them because it's different WebGl engines, so using Blend4Web addon for Blender you can export only to Blend4Web engine.

You can find a good way to make flime using only Blender Internal Render and Blend4Web possibilities [in this video](https://youtu.be/fSi8Xzs6fSc?t=2m58s) from our conference.